# bash: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: shell, ls

I am using a web terminal ubuntu 20.04 to learn shell and everything was working fine.
suddenly I started getting this error message when I invoked the ls command
when I tried listing my current directory it came up with the error message bellow

bash: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Answer (score 1):

Well, this means something is wrong with the file `/usr/bin/ls` , like it is for a different computer "architecture".

Investigate when `ls` worked previously for you, go back to that and see what the location of the `ls` executable was that worked. Use `which` command to find the location.

If this does not point you in the right direction, you need to give more details - start from the point when `ls` is working and then give all the steps you are doing until it stops working.